# Observable array length undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I wrote code to filter data from an observable array, but it always throws an error saying length is undefined.

Here code of my function:

```
 self.filterShowsByTheatre=function(teatr)
 {
    var stageid;
    if (teatr != staryteatr)
    {
        if (teatr == "") {
            self.Shows.removeAll();
            self.loadShows();
        }
        else {
            for (var x = 0; x < self.stages().lenght; x++) {
                console.log(self.stages()[x].TheatreName);
                if (self.stages()[x].TheatreName == teatr)
                    stageid = self.stages()[x].StageId;
            }
            var temp = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < self.Shows().length; i++) {
                if(self.Shows()[i].StageId==stageid)
                {
                    temp.push(self.Shows()[i]);
                }
            }
            self.Shows.removeAll();
            for (var z = 0; z < temp.length; z++) {
                self.Shows.push(temp[z])
            }
        }
        staryteatr = teatr;
    }       
  }
```

And here's my View Model:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.stages = ko.observableArray();
    self.Shows = ko.observableArray();
    self.loadShows = function()
      {
        Here Shows.push...
      }
    self.loadStages=function()
      {
        here stages.push...
      }
    self.loadShows();
    self.loadstages();
}

function stage(id,Tid,Sname,Tname,adress, lat, long) {
    var self = this;
    self.StageId = id;
    self.TheatreId = Tid;
    self.Stagename = Sname;
    self.TheatreName = Tname;
    self.Adress = adress;
    self.lat = lat;
    self.long = long;
}
function show(showId, stageId, showName, directorName)
{
    var self = this;
    self.ShowId = showId;
    self.StageId = stageId;
    self.ShowName = showName;
    self.DirectorName = directorName;
}

var model = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

When I try to read the length from eg. `loadShows()` it works, but for `filterShows` it doesn't.

Comment: please post the code you use to push items into your arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spelling mistake:

```
self.stages().lenght
```

should be

```
self.stages().length
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how could I made such a mistake while using intellisense :)

Comment: You made the same mistake in your question so I have a feeling you're going to see that error again ;-)

Comment: Damn, same dumb error for me!